# F#: System.Net.WebException

Tags: exception, web, f#

I am new to programming and F# is my first language. I am currently still very unfamiliar with .NET APIs.

As a beginner's project, I want to scrape a website. I want to write a function that, given a specific URL, automatically downloads all the HTML contents on that page. However, if the URL is invalid, rather than throwing a System.Net.WebException message, I want to return the Boolean output "False" instead.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
let noSuchURL (url: string) =
    let html = downloadHtmlFromUrl url
    let regexPattern = @"<title>Page not found</title>"
    let matchResult = Regex.IsMatch(html, regexPattern)
    matchResult
```

(I have tested the downloadHtmlFromUrl function in F# interactive, and it works fine.)

I realised that the code above does not return a Boolean value in the event that the address is invalid. Instead, System.Net.WebException is thrown, with the message "System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found".

What changes can I make to get a Boolean output?

Comment: A WebException (actually all exceptions) have a message property that describes what went wrong. So, what is wrong? Is the URL valid, empty, not-existent?

Comment: This is the error message: "System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

Comment: What are you trying to do? An invalid address will raise an exception, because the server itself will return a 404 error response instead of a web page. It doesn't have to return anything in the body. Either catch the exception or change the code of downloadHtmlFromUrl so it doesn't throw on error. Eg. use HttpClient instead of WebClient and check the response status code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe catch the exception?

```
let noSuchURL (url: string) =
  try
    let html = downloadHtmlFromUrl url
    let regexPattern = @"<title>Page not found</title>"
    let matchResult = Regex.IsMatch(html, regexPattern)
    matchResult
  with :? System.Net.WebException -> false
```

One caveat: this program will return `false` if there is a `WebException`, no matter for what reason that exception being raised. If you want specifically to return `false` on 404 responses, you'll have to look closer at the `WebException`:

```
let noSuchURL (url: string) =
  try
    let html = downloadHtmlFromUrl url
    let regexPattern = @"<title>Page not found</title>"
    let matchResult = Regex.IsMatch(html, regexPattern)
    matchResult
  with 
    :? System.Net.WebException as e 
       when e.Status = WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError ||
            e.Status = WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure
       -> false
```

For more on exceptions in F#, take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233194.aspx.